# How to set assignee with Jira Script Runner?

Tags: groovy, jira

I want to set the Assignee based on Reporter. I wrote a script for that but doesn't work.

```
import com.atlassian.jira.user.util.UserManager
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueManager
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue
import com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.CustomFieldManager
import com.atlassian.jira.event.type.EventDispatchOption

CustomField srcField = ComponentManager.getInstance().getCustomFieldManager().getCustomFieldObjectByName("Reporter")

cfwt = issue.getCustomFieldValue(sccField)

if(cfwt == "User Name"){
  MutableIssue myIssue = issue
  IssueManager issueManager = ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager()
  UserManager userManager = ComponentAccessor.getUserManager()
  myIssue.setCustomFieldValue(reviewerCustomField, assignee)
  issueManager.updateIssue(userManager.getUser("User Name"), myIssue, EventDispatchOption.DO_NOT_DISPATCH, false)
}
```

When run, I get the following error:

> error:
>   startup failed: Script6.groovy: 12: unable to resolve class CustomField @ line 12, column 13. CustomField srcField = ComponentManager.getInstance().getCustomFieldManager().getCustomFieldObjectByName("Reporter") ^ 1 error

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an import:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.CustomField
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for the answer. now  i get no error messages but assignee doesn't work either.

Answer (score -1):

```
cfwt = issue.getCustomFieldValue(sccField)
```

sccField - here
CustomField srcField
srcField - here

You use this script as post-function?